# Why am I getting an error when trying to install and run npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install and run npm in a linux environment. I have executed the below code to try and achieve this

```
nvm install v11.0.0
nvm use v11.0.0
npm install
npm start
```

When I execute npm install in the command line I keep getting the following error message. Any advice to help this run is much appreciated.

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/andrewoca/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/andrewoca/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/package.json'
npm WARN pythonProject No description
npm WARN pythonProject No repository field.
npm WARN pythonProject No README data
npm WARN pythonProject No license field.
```

Comment: `npm install` is looking for `package.json` in order to see what it needs to do. Since you dont have it - you get the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before running npm install, create an npm project.

This can be done with `npm init -y`

Now you can use `npm install <package name>`

Comment: I saw the comment you tried to add @Andrewoca now you would do npm install react-scripts or any other packages you need

Comment: I did try the above however I now have gotten a rake of errors. I guess I will have to do some further research into it

Answer (score 1):

`npm install` is looking for `package.json` in order to see what it needs to do. Since you dont have it - you get the errors.

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install